# Preview image in node view using Python API

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on

I am making a python addon for Blender 2.80 with a node tree format and I want to preview a loaded image in the node itself. I got this idea from the Compositor, the image attached shows the default Compositor view with the functionality I mentioned above.

Is this possible with the current python API? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Added screenshot of this feature from Compositor

[image]

Comment: Have a look around this: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/gpu.html#rendering-the-3d-view-into-a-texture (not sure that can do it in your context, though)